# What difference between using IController in mvc 4 and mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried write code what is working in MVC 4 using VS2012.

RouteConfig.cs

```
namespace MvcApplication2012
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SayHello",
                url: "hello",
                defaults: new { controller = "hello" }
                );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

IController.cs

```
namespace MvcApplication2012.Controllers
{
    public class HelloController : IController
    {
        public void Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine in MVC 4 using VS2012, but not work in MVC 5 using VS2015.

What is defference? Why it not work?

Returns error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wh23.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bassically I found answer, I forgot set class HelloController as public:( But now all is works